# Телеграм бот выдаёт ошибку TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telebot

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.
Во время работы бота при подтверждении того, что город выбран правильно программа останавливается и выдаёт ошибку. Что делать?

Код бота:

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types

# creating
TOKEN = ""
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

base_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
button_weather = types.KeyboardButton("Узнать погоду в моём городе.")
button_change = types.KeyboardButton("Изменить мой город.")

base_markup.add(button_weather, button_change)


# creating buttons
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEEPWZiOgABRUBmN6NNKOsBU3mTh8ag_8gAAkwCAALKAwYLElZjg2wiVFIjBA')

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_help = types.KeyboardButton("Начать")
    button_start = types.KeyboardButton("Помощь")

    markup.add(button_help, button_start)

    # sending message
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот который поможет тебе узнать погоду в твоём городе.".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


# getting messages and replying them
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Начать":

        city_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button_moscow = types.KeyboardButton("Москва")
        button_spb = types.KeyboardButton("Санкт-Петербург")
        button_novosibirsk = types.KeyboardButton("Новосибирск")
        button_yekateriburg = types.KeyboardButton("Екатеринбург")
        button_kazan = types.KeyboardButton("Казань")
        button_nizhnynovgorod = types.KeyboardButton("Нижный Новгород")
        button_chelyabinsk = types.KeyboardButton("Челябинск")
        button_other = types.KeyboardButton("Другой город")

        city_markup.add(button_moscow, button_spb, button_novosibirsk, button_yekateriburg, button_kazan,
                        button_nizhnynovgorod, button_chelyabinsk, button_other)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Выбери свой город:", reply_markup=city_markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, group_number)

    elif message.text == "Помощь":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Нажми кнопку <b>\'Начать\'</b> и выбери один из предложенных городов. \nЕсли твоего города нет в списке, нажми <b>\'Другой город\'</b>. \nПодтверди название города.\nБот выдаст тебе погоду в твоём городе.\n<b>Создатель: Батиев Ростислав</b>",
                         parse_mode='html')


def group_number(message):
    global city
    city = message.text

    answer_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_yes = types.KeyboardButton("Да")
    button_no = types.KeyboardButton("Нет")

    answer_markup.add(button_yes, button_no)

    if city == "Другой город":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите название Вашего города:", parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, another_city)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш город - {}, верно?".format(city), parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=answer_markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, city)


def city(message):
    global answer
    answer = message.text

    city_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_moscow = types.KeyboardButton("Москва")
    button_spb = types.KeyboardButton("Санкт-Петербург")
    button_novosibirsk = types.KeyboardButton("Новосибирск")
    button_yekateriburg = types.KeyboardButton("Екатеринбург")
    button_kazan = types.KeyboardButton("Казань")
    button_nizhnynovgorod = types.KeyboardButton("Нижный Новгород")
    button_chelyabinsk = types.KeyboardButton("Челябинск")
    button_other = types.KeyboardButton("Другой город")

    city_markup.add(button_moscow, button_spb, button_novosibirsk, button_yekateriburg, button_kazan,
                    button_nizhnynovgorod, button_chelyabinsk, button_other)

    if answer == "Да":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Погода в вашем городе:\n", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=base_markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_text_messages)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Выбери свой город:", reply_markup=city_markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, group_number)


def another_city(message):
    city = message.text

    answer_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_yes = types.KeyboardButton("Да")
    button_no = types.KeyboardButton("Нет")

    answer_markup.add(button_yes, button_no)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш город - {}, верно?".format(city), parse_mode='html',
                     reply_markup=answer_markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, city)


# checking if messages were sent to bot
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/WeatherBot/main.py", line 123, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WeatherBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 658, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WeatherBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 720, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WeatherBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 680, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WeatherBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WeatherBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 87, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что вы одинаково назвали переменную и функцию, и когда вы хотели перейти на следующий шаг с помощью `bot.register_next_step_handler`, при этом в аргументах указывая переменную `city` программа думала что вы пытаетесь вызвать переменную (как бы это странно не звучало):

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

# creating
TOKEN = ""
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

base_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
button_weather = types.KeyboardButton("Узнать погоду в моём городе.")
button_change = types.KeyboardButton("Изменить мой город.")

base_markup.add(button_weather, button_change)


# creating buttons
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEEPWZiOgABRUBmN6NNKOsBU3mTh8ag_8gAAkwCAALKAwYLElZjg2wiVFIjBA')

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_help = types.KeyboardButton("Начать")
    button_start = types.KeyboardButton("Помощь")

    markup.add(button_help, button_start)

    # sending message
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот который поможет тебе узнать погоду в твоём городе.".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


# getting messages and replying them
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Начать":

        city_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button_moscow = types.KeyboardButton("Москва")
        button_spb = types.KeyboardButton("Санкт-Петербург")
        button_novosibirsk = types.KeyboardButton("Новосибирск")
        button_yekateriburg = types.KeyboardButton("Екатеринбург")
        button_kazan = types.KeyboardButton("Казань")
        button_nizhnynovgorod = types.KeyboardButton("Нижный Новгород")
        button_chelyabinsk = types.KeyboardButton("Челябинск")
        button_other = types.KeyboardButton("Другой город")

        city_markup.add(button_moscow, button_spb, button_novosibirsk, button_yekateriburg, button_kazan,
                        button_nizhnynovgorod, button_chelyabinsk, button_other)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Выбери свой город:", reply_markup=city_markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, group_number)

    elif message.text == "Помощь":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Нажми кнопку <b>\'Начать\'</b> и выбери один из предложенных городов. \nЕсли твоего города нет в списке, нажми <b>\'Другой город\'</b>. \nПодтверди название города.\nБот выдаст тебе погоду в твоём городе.\n<b>Создатель: Батиев Ростислав</b>",
                         parse_mode='html')


def group_number(message):
    global city
    city = message.text

    answer_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_yes = types.KeyboardButton("Да")
    button_no = types.KeyboardButton("Нет")

    answer_markup.add(button_yes, button_no)
    print("here2")
    if city == "Другой город":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите название Вашего города:", parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, another_city)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш город - {}, верно?".format(city), parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=answer_markup)
######################################################
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, city2)


def city2(message):
######################################################
    global answer
    answer = message.text

    city_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_moscow = types.KeyboardButton("Москва")
    button_spb = types.KeyboardButton("Санкт-Петербург")
    button_novosibirsk = types.KeyboardButton("Новосибирск")
    button_yekateriburg = types.KeyboardButton("Екатеринбург")
    button_kazan = types.KeyboardButton("Казань")
    button_nizhnynovgorod = types.KeyboardButton("Нижный Новгород")
    button_chelyabinsk = types.KeyboardButton("Челябинск")
    button_other = types.KeyboardButton("Другой город")

    city_markup.add(button_moscow, button_spb, button_novosibirsk, button_yekateriburg, button_kazan,
                    button_nizhnynovgorod, button_chelyabinsk, button_other)
    if answer == "Да":

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Погода в вашем городе:\n", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=base_markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_text_messages)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Выбери свой город:", reply_markup=city_markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, group_number)


def another_city(message):
    city = message.text

    answer_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_yes = types.KeyboardButton("Да")
    button_no = types.KeyboardButton("Нет")

    answer_markup.add(button_yes, button_no)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш город - {}, верно?".format(city), parse_mode='html',
                     reply_markup=answer_markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, city)


# checking if messages were sent to bot
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!